# Extract the value of multiple selection checklist in InfoPath2010

Tags: infopath

I need to extract the value of multiple selection checklist in a text box, is it possible to do?
I have tried to extract it out using multiple checklist value from datasource, multiple checklist value manually key in but both case doesn't work, by applying rules in the text box still shows empty...

only single by single checkbox does show the assign value in textbox.

Please guide me in possibilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a little bit of code to get all the values into a single textbox. The multiple selection checkbox is stored as a repeating field - so you can write code to parse the DOM XML and iterate through the nodes and create a delimited string to show in the textbox (use the DOM `selectNodes` function and standard XML parsing).

A full example would be a little bit long for this forum but please post/ask specific questions if you run into issues. It isn't that terribly hard - just a bit of a pain since it is code based.

Comment: I manage to do populate the value in textbox by clicking the button as the code set inside the button edit form code
----------------------------------------------------
XPathNavigator root = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iter = root.Select("//my:myFields/my:check/my:box", NamespaceManager);
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
while (iter.MoveNext())
     {
      string value = iter.Current.Value;
      sb.Append(value);
      sb.Append("; ");
      }
  root.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:value",
  NamespaceManager).SetValue(sb.ToString());

Comment: Where my:box(Xpath) is multiple Checkbox and my:value(Xpath) is textbox

Answer (score 1):

public void CTRL20_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Write your code here.

```
        XPathNavigator root = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator iter = root.Select("//my:myFields/my:check/my:box",
          NamespaceManager);
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            string value = iter.Current.Value;
            sb.Append(value);
            sb.Append("; ");
        }
       root.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:value",
          NamespaceManager).SetValue(sb.ToString()); 
   }
```